# Converting Particle System Hair to Curves Hair that follows figure when Shapekey loaded

Tags: hair

New Curves Hair system was implemented in Blender 3.3.

I have converted my old Particle System hair to Curves hair, using the method described in [this](https://youtu.be/B_duIE3wyF8?t=408) Youtube video.  However, my issue is that the hair doesnt follow my character when i dial in shapekeys for the character.

The steps i took were as follows:

1. Converted Particle System Hair to Curves (using special menu in Particle Systems Properties menu)
2. Under Curves properties, I have updated the Surface to be my scalp mesh, and the UV Map to my scalp mesh UV Map
3. In Sculpt Mode, I have clicked 'Snap to nearest surface'
4. **I then dialled in a shapekey on my character (which has the scalp connected via a surface deform modifier), and the scalp moved but the hair stayed where it was.**

[image]

Comment: Is this a true *Surface Deform* modifier -or- is it a *Geometry Nodes* modifier, named *Surface Deform*, with a single *Deform Curves on Surface* node in it? The last one is the correct one. It must be on the *HairHead* object (curves). And the *HairHead* object should be a child of the surface object (*Scalp_HairHead2*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your screenshot. **The *HairHead* curves** object in the outliner **has *no* modifier**. There is no blue wrench icon. But the *Scalp_HairHead2* object has one. This looks wrong.

**The curves object *HairHead* must have a *Geometry Nodes* modifier** with a single ***Deform Curves on Surface node*** in it.

Furthermore, the *HairHead* object should be a child of the surface object *Scalp_HairHead2*.

[image: gn modifier]

If you add a *Curve > Empty Hair* object to a selected object (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) then Blender ...

- creates a *Curves* object
- makes it a child of the select object
- enters the values for *Surface > Surface* and *Surface > UV Map* in the *Object Data Properties* panel
- adds a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to the *Curves* object. It's needed when the mesh is deformed by an *Armature* modifier or shape keys. **Note:** It's named *Surface Deform* but it's a *Geometry Nodes* modifier. **Don't confuse it with the true *Surface Deform* modifier.**

If you convert a *Hair Particle System* to the new *Hair Curves* you need to do steps 2 to 4 manually.

[image: curves settings]

Shape key test:
[image: example animation]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. The only additional thing I needed to do was ensure that the 'Add Rest Position' box was ticked under Object Data Properties on my scalp mesh.