Is it possible to convert Hair Particles to the new Geometry Hair Nodes?
I have a hair system done with Particle Hair and I want to convert it into Hair Curves so I can play with the normals of individual strands.
Is there a way to convert it?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276057/converting-particle-system-hair-to-curves-hair-that-follows-figure-when-shapekey and YT video here.
